# rpart formula parameter usage: "NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments"

Tags: r, rpart

in simple linear regression, having a data frame, we can use that to write the formula easier, for example:

```
lm(my_dep_var ~ .-var1, data=my_df)
```

will return the model with the vars except `var1` as indipendent variables in our model. 

 However, when I try to use the same formulation in `rpart` function, it seem to have an error:

```
> tree1 <- rpart(Reverse ~ .-Circuit, data=train[a], method="class", minbucket=25)
Error in rpart(Reverse ~ . - Circuit, data = train[a], method = "class",  : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
>
```

I have no NA is my data, and the rpart command without the minus(but with the dot: `Reverse ~ .`) seem to work well. So it seems I can't use minus sign in `rpart` formula.
Is that indeed the case ? where can I read this kind of thing in the documentation ?

EDIT: here is a simplified code that generates this kind of error:

```
var1 <- as.factor(c(1,1,1,0,1))
var2 <- c(0,0,0,0,0)
var3 <- factor(c("2", "9", "5", "5", "5"), levels=c("2","3","4","5","8","9"))
var4 <- factor(c("EA", "EA", "EA", "EA", "JP"), levels=c("EA", "CR", "CA", "JP"))
dtf <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4)
rpart(var1 ~.-var4 ,data=dtf, method="class", minbucket=25)
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: new code.

I think the problem were the character/factor variables. To solve the problem, I had to create a data frame with dummy variables.

```
# Sample size
N <- 10000

# Creating the df
var1 <- sample(c(0,1),N,replace = T)
var2 <- sample(c(0),N,replace = T)
var3 <- as.factor(sample(c("2", "9", "5", "5", "5"),N,replace = T))
var4 <- as.factor(sample(c("EA", "EA", "EA", "EA", "JP"),N,replace = T))
dtf <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4)

# Loading the package
require(rpart)
require(caret)

# Hot Enconding - Creating dummy variables
dummies <- dummyVars(~ ., data = dtf)
dtf2 <- as.data.frame(predict(dummies, newdata = dtf))

# Fitting the model
fit <- rpart(var1 ~. - var4.EA,data=dtf2, method="class", minbucket=25)
```

I hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that in few hours...please stay tuned. I'll provide the output of head, str, and summary. anything else you think might be useful ?

Comment: Try to create the data frame like df <- data.frame(...) and post it so that we can quickly use the same data that you have.

Comment: see my edited post. I have created simplified df that generate this error. I noticed error is not happening with -var2 instead of -var4. please let me know if you can trace what causes the error.

Comment: Well, thanks. I could solve that problem other ways. I was more interested with the question of *why* this is happening, and where can I read about this kind of behavior in the documentation. I just don't understand why var2+var3 is processed differently than . -var4.. and what exactly cause the error.